# Android-Transparent Panel

Tags: android

I am new to android.I need to create a Transparent Panel .
Can any one help me with same code..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: yes, you have many question, which you got an answer, and you didn't accept any of them. You should accept the right answer!

Comment: 27 questios with many answers, but still 0% acceept rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TransparentPanel is not a class native to Android itself. The only context where I have encountered it is in a tutorial available at :

[link text](http://www.androidapps.org/tag/mapview)

I hope this may be of some use to you. You can download the source for the tutorial from that page.

Answer (score 0):

```
setAlpha(128);
```

Your question doesn't make sense, you'll need to be more specific about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id=...
                    android:layout_height=....
                    android:layout_width=....
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```